# Error: The request could not be completed (Internal Server Error) on Azure Mobile Services

Tags: c#, azure, windows-8.1, backend, azure-mobile-services

I am building a Windows 8.1 Metro app that connects to a server backend hosted on Azure. Right now, for testing, when I tap the button on the app screen, it triggers a function to insert a value into a database.

The code for that is here:

```
private async void SubmitClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      Companies Quiblify = new Companies {Name = "CompanyX"};
      await App.MobileService.GetTable<Companies>().InsertAsync(Quiblify);
    }
}
```

When I run this app and tap the button, I get this error:

```
An exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException'  occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The request could not be completed.  (Internal Server Error)
```

What is my problem?

EDIT: Here is the server side code.

```
// POST tables/Companies
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostCompany(Companies item)
{
    Companies current = await InsertAsync(item);
     return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
}
```

Here is the error log:

```
Exception=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "master" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'dNDCkODBwDLogin_ModernPOSBackend'.
This session has been assigned a tracing ID of 'bafdb889-b1b9-42a1-ace5-101ed382c1d2'.  Provide this tracing ID to customer support when you need assistance.
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass34.<UsingConnection>b__32()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
   at System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
   at System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__e()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.EntityDomainManager`1.<InsertAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.TableController`1.<InsertAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
ClientConnectionId:8edddc79-b06c-4c06-8cd2-aedc688e2c99
Error Number:4060,State:1,Class:11, Id=d3a27e91-15b5-4cd3-a8a5-761434cc363b, Category='App.Controllers.Tables'
```

Comment: Did you deploy your backend project?  If you're using the .NET backend, there is a sever project that you need to open in Visual Studio then deploy using "Publish". See this tutorial for more information: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/

Comment: You'll need to share any server logs and relevant code to debug. The issue isn't necessarily your client.

Comment: @lindydonna Yes, the project is deployed. It does not work when debugging locally either.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT I added the server side code but do not have any logs because it is hosted with Azure Mobile Services.

Comment: There should be logs in the logging tab in the portal.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT I found the logs and posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're connecting to the master schema for your database, but the connection string user doesn't have permissions. You should edit the MS_TableConnectionString in the portal, or create a new connection string and use that one. You should also make sure that you are using the right database schema.

Here's a guide with more information: http://hashtagfail.com/post/84964727000/mobile-services-net-backend-connection-strings

See also:

- [Creating a Model with Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907#codefirst)
- [FirstEntity Framework Code First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542)

Comment: I did that, and I can connect to my database now.  However, I am getting this error: The operation failed with the following error: 'Invalid column name 'Deleted'.
Invalid column name 'Version'.
Invalid column name 'CreatedAt'.
Invalid column name 'UpdatedAt'.'. I am not inserting anything in these columns and I don't want them either.  They don't even exist in my database!